# Tar file to another directory while keeping the original filename

Tags: linux, shell, tar

I've been tasked to help automate some of our archiving process. I am only a beginner in Unix/Linux so I would appreciate some help. One of the request is to tar any files in folder1 and put the tar file into folder2.

A single file is dropped in folder 1 every hour. The format is like this: 
ABC_TIMESTAMP.gz. (However, it may not always be "ABC", it could be BDC or similar).

So basically, I need to tar /folder1/ABC_TIMESTAMP.gz to /folder2/ABC_TIMESTAMP.gz.tar.

Then finally, delete the original file in folder1.

Comment: You can run tar and then mv.

Comment: That works. This would take care of the moving part. However, the main issue is still to tar the file(s) that come in. So if 2 files come in, ABC_TIMESTAMP.gz and DEF_TIMESTAM.gz, script my command to create ABC_TIMESTAMP.gz.tar and DEF_TIMESTAM.gz.tar? The files need to be tar-ed separately and not lumped into one giant file.

Answer (score 0):

Try it out. I have assumed that all files in folder1 are .gz format. 
Write down this script and run.

```
#!/bin/bash

ls folder1 >tmp.file

while read line
do
        tar -cf folder2/"$line".tar -C folder1 "$line"
        rm folder1/$line
done < tmp.file
```

Comment: Hm....I could be doing it wrong but the files in folder1 got deleted but nothing was created in folder2

Comment: Do you get any error?